# How to update values from another table with conditions

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I want to update values from table df1 with values from df2, only updating null values or zeros.
I can do it with data.table or dplyr, but I can´t automate to all columns.

```
#data.table
df1 <- data.frame(x1=1:4, x2=c('a','b', NA, 'd'), x3=c(0,0,2,2), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df2 <- data.frame(x1=2:3, x2=c("zz", "qq"),x3=6:7, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

require(data.table)
setDT(df1); setDT(df2)

df1[df2, on = .(x1), x2 := ifelse(is.na(x2) | x2 == 0 ,i.x2,x2)]

#dplyr
require(dplyr)
require(dplyr)
inner_join(df1,df2,by = c("x1" = "x1")) %>% 
  transmute(x1 = x1,
            x2 =ifelse(is.na(x2.x) | x2.x == 0,x2.y,x2.x),
            x3 =ifelse(is.na(x3.x) | x3.x == 0,x3.y,x3.x))
```

With dplyr at least I can manually adding columns getting the expected output, the problem is real dataframe has so much columns. Therefore I want to iterate across columns to achieved the task.

What I´ve tried:

```
# dplyr + apply
inner_join(df1,df2,by = c("x1" = "x1")) %>% 
  cbind(.$x1, 
        apply(.[-1],2, function(cname) ifelse(is.na(cname) | cname == 'b',paste(cname, ".x", collapse = ""),paste(cname, ".y", collapse = "")))
  )

# data.table with for
for (cname in names(df1)[!names(df1) %in% c("x1")]) {
  df1[i = df2, on = .(x1), j = cname := {function (x) ifelse(is.na(x) | x == 'b',i.x,x)} (cname)
        , with = FALSE]
} 

# data.table + lapply
df1[i = df2, on = .(x1)  ,names(df1)[!names(df1) %in% c("x1")] := lapply(df1[,names(df1)[!names(df1) %in% c("x1")],with=FALSE],
                           function(x) ifelse(is.na(x) | x == 0,df2.x,df1.x))]
```

Comment: Would be good if you shared expected output. Should row 1 stay as 0 if it can't be updated?

Comment: @sindri_baldur I guess the expected output is `inner_join(df1,df2,by = c("x1" = "x1")) %>% 
  transmute(x1 = x1,
            x2 =ifelse(is.na(x2.x) | x2.x == 0,x2.y,x2.x),
            x3 =ifelse(is.na(x3.x) | x3.x == 0,x3.y,x3.x))` without doing it manually for all the column combinations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using base R, you can create a function to replace `NA` and 0 with corresponding values from another column

```
replace_na_0 <- function(x) {
   ifelse(is.na(x[[1]]) | x[[1]] == 0,x[[2]],x[[1]])
}
```

Do merge and pass group of columns by removing their postfix (`.x`, `.y)` to `replace_na_0` function

```
temp_df <- merge(df1, df2, by = "x1")

cbind(temp_df[1], sapply(split.default(temp_df[-1], 
       sub("\\..*", "", names(temp_df)[-1])), replace_na_0))

#  x1 x2 x3
#1  2  b  6
#2  3 qq  2
```

Answer (score 1):

For `data.table`, you can use:

```
for (x in setdiff(names(df1), "x1")) {
    df1[is.na(get(x)) ! get(x)==0, (x) := df2[.SD, on=.(x1), get(x)]]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure `data.table` approach...

The melting process takes care of all columns you wish to 'fill, putting them all in one single set of columns (variable and value).
Then fill in all the 0/NA values using an update join (=fast!)
Finally, recast everything back to it's original shape.

```
library(data.table)
#set to data.table
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)
#melt to long
melt1 <- melt(df1, id.vars = "x1" )
melt2 <- melt(df2, id.vars = "x1" )
#join all values with value NA or 0
melt1[ is.na(value) | value == 0, 
       value := melt1[ is.na( value) | value == 0,][ melt2, value := i.value, on = .(x1, variable) ]$value][]
#cast to original wide format
dcast( melt1, x1 ~ variable )
```

**output**

```
#    x1 x2 x3
# 1:  1  a  0
# 2:  2  b  6
# 3:  3 qq  2
# 4:  4  d  2
```